# Modify the return of a windows Shortcut Menu Handlers and echo it

Tags: windows, command, contextmenu, command-prompt

I am trying to create a shortcut menu handler for that will take the file path provided by %1 and modify it to remove the drive letter and insert a domain name.

I've tried many different ways I could think of but it all ends up adding things to the end. For example this works normally in command-line

```
echo %v:S:=domain.com%|clip
```

Assuming v is already set to the file path.

But when i try to run a similar command like this via the shortcut menu handler

```
cmd.exe /c echo %1:S:=domain.com|clip
```

But that just gives me something like this:

```
S:\File\Path\file.file:S:=domain.com
```

I've tried setting the path to an environment variable and then replacing the drive letter but it still yields the same results.

```
cmd.exe /c set v=%1 && echo %v:S:=domain.com%|clip
```

These work as expected in command prompt, so I don't understand why it's not working as expected in a shortcut menu handler.

Any advice? Am I even going about this the right way? Also is it possible to restrict this shortcut menu to only showing up on a specific drive?

Comment: `cmd.exe /e /v /c set "v=%1" ^& echo !v:S:=domain.com!^|clip`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything, nothing is copied to the clipboard

Comment: `cmd.exe /e /v /c set "v=%1" && echo !v:S:=domain.com!|clip` this worked